# How can I make the text within a div change when I click a button?

Tags: html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#getQuote').on("click", functon() {
    $('.message').html("Here is the message");
  });
});

</script>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <h1>Random Quote Machine</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="well message">

        The quote will go here
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row text-center">
      <button id="getQuote" class="btn btn-primary">Get Quote </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Hi I'm new to programming and I'm using codepen.io to do this. I was wondering why when I click the button "Get Message" the message in the div does not change to the new message. By the way I am learning to code through freecodecamp and this code worked on freecodecamp's website but not on codepen. so I am wondering what I am doing wrong. On codepen, the error that I get is "Unexpected Token {". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Minor Type: functon() != function()**

You currently have a typo as you are using `functon` instead of `function` in your event handler, which will throw everything else off syntactically :

```
// Previously you had $('#getQuote').on("click",functon() {
$('#getQuote').on("click", function() {
    $('.message').html("Here is the message");
});
```

**Double-check jQuery is referenced.**

If that doesn't resolve the issue, you'll need to ensure that jQuery is referencing prior to any code that is using it :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<!-- Reference jQuery before any other scripts that rely on it -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#getQuote').on("click", function() {
      $('.message').html("Here is the message");
    });
  });
</script>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <h1>Random Quote Machine</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="well message">

        The quote will go here
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row text-center">
      <button id="getQuote" class="btn btn-primary">Get Quote</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the script that you are using is jQuery. To enable jQuery library, you HAVE TO add it to your code by adding below

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

That will load the jQuery library for you to use in your script.

Another way of doing it is by downloading it and referencing its path.

I have tried running your code and yes as Rion has already said, typo is causing the problem. Change `functon()` to `function()`

It is a very common mistake to make as a newbie. Keep up the good work!